# Is it possible for a function to be differentiable at only one point?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was taking a complex analysis class today, and we looked at the function f(z)=|z|^2 (with the domain over the complex numbers). It is continuous, but it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations at only one point. Does that mean that the function is differentiable at that point but at no other point? Is it even possible for a function to only be differentiable at only one point?

Comment: Precisely, the function is differentiable only at $z=0$. So $f(z)=|z|^2$ is differentiable at a point but nowhere-analytic, since to be analytic, a function must be differentiable,e.g., satisfy C-R , in an open set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, functions can be differentiable at only one point, and $f(z) = |z|^2$ is a prime example.

An additional remark:

Don't forget that satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations at a point is not sufficient for the function to be differentiable at that point. The partial derivatives of the component functions must also be continuous at that point.